# How to use Facebook Connect and Facebook Application android

Tags: android, api, facebook

How to use Facebook Connect in android to get permission from Facebook to update status from my application.

Please give some example.
I'm struggling with this for past one week.

Thanks,
Shanmugam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try this https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/?

Comment: Hi Umair,I used Facebook android SDK and even succeded in it. But now how can i use only Status update facility of Facebook SDK.Can you give small snippet of code how to use status update using Facebook SDk. Please dont give same code in that examples. Give me very simple code tat will be helpful

Comment: You mean to say, you want to post status on behalf of your user?